# How can I form an if statement to repeat methods if variables are null?

Tags: ios, if-statement, crash, null

I want to repeat my two methods which are in separate view controller. Here is my code (please add a comment if the code is not clear to explain situation):

First View Controller:

```
-(void)GettingVariable {
    NSString *VariableGotFromSVC = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] VariableGotFromSVC;
    NSNumberFormatter * NsFormatterMethod= [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [NsFormatterMethod setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    myNumberVariable = [NsFormatterMethod numberFromString:VariableGotFromSVC];

    if (!myNumberVariable) {
        Ayarlar *SecondVC = [[Ayarlar alloc]init];
        [SecondVC performSelector:@selector(touchesBegan:withEvent:)];
    }

    NSLog(@"mynumbervariable:%@", myNumberVariable);
}
```

Second View Controller:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setVariable:VariableTextField.text];

    MekanListesi *FirstVC=[[MekanListesi alloc]init];
    [FirstVC GettingVariable];
}
```

That code crashes with that message:

> 0x1e640b0:  cmpl   (%eax), %ecx

Comment: Objective-C conventions are to begin method names and instance variable names with a lower case character unless the name starts with a very well known acronym. This allows others to more easily understand code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't call `touchesBegan` directly. This method is called when a touch has been detected on the receiver.

Second, apple doc states about the `touchesBegan` method that:

> If you override this method without calling super (a common use
>   pattern), you must also override the other methods for handling touch
>   events, if only as stub (empty) implementations.

So first of all remove the direct call to `touchesBegan` from your code and move it to another method.

Second, if you implement `touchesBegan` you should call `[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]`;

**EDIT**

If I understand correctly what you want (if not please correct me) you want to execute the code from `touchesBegan` when the text field is selected and when the if statement is false. 
So my previous statements are still valid `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` is a method provided by the system and called when a touch event is detected on the responder view so you shouldn't call it directly in your code like `[SecondVC performSelector:@selector(touchesBegan:withEvent:)];`.
If you want to execute the same code when the user taps on a  UITextFiled and when the if statement is false you should extract that code into a separate method and call that method from `touchesBegan` and when the if statement is false.

Comment: In second view controller, i am using a textfield. so touchesBegan method is activated when touches has been detected at second view controller. but i thing you are saying that i can not activate that method from first view controller. So how can i activate that method when if statement is not satisfied?